# is it possible to check the filesize of a file before uploading it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

i am trying to upload a file to the webserver in my asp.net mvc 2 webapplication. This only works when the file size is less than 102Mb.

This is my setting in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
</system.web>
```

can i check before i upload my file what the filesize is so it wont throw an error when it reaches over the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx). You can check the file size on the client using some of the file upload plugins out there ([Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), ...).

Comment: @user603007, those are client file upload plugins. They don't care about what is installed on the web server. They are browser dependent.